# Why can't javascript find my functions?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I made a puzzle game using HTML5, just now I tried to add local storage to the game, but failed.

I wrote three functions. The problem is: If I put all the functions in one .js file, none is defined when debugging(via chrome). If I split these three functions to another file and add a  tag to the .html file, I'm told these are not defined.

So how to solve this problem?

Sorry for my poor English, hope you understand what I means.

Here are my functions and html file.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Puzzle</title>
<script src="puzzle-localstorage.js"></script>
<script src="puzzle.js"></script></script>
</head>

<body onLoad="Init()" onkeydown="keydown()">
<p align="center">
    <canvas id="board" height="600" width="600" style="border-style:double">
        Your Browser doesn't support canvas
    </canvas>
</p>
<p id="moves">Moves: <span id="movecount">0</span>
<input type="number" id="boardEdgeNum" value="3"/>
<input type="file" id="imgSrc"/>

</p>
```

```
function supportsLocalStorage() {
try {
return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
} catch (e) {
return false;
    }
}



function saveGameState() {
if (!supportsLocalStorage()) { return false; }
localStorage["puzzle.boardEdge"] = boardEdge;
localStorage["puzzle.blockPixel"] = blockPixel;
for (var i = 0; i < boardEdge; i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<boardEdge;j++){
        localStorage["puzzle.gameStatus."+i+j] = gameStatus[i][j];
    }
}
localStorage["puzzle.image.src"]=imgElement.src;
localStorage["puzzle.move.count"] = moveCount.textContent;
if(gameInProgress)localStorage["puzzle.game.in.progress"] = "true";
else localStorage["puzzle.game.in.progress"]="false";
localStorage["puzzle.empty.block.X"] = emptyBlock.X;
localStorage["puzzle.empty.block.Y"] = emptyBlock.Y;
return true;
}

function resumeGame() {
if (!supportsLocalStorage()) {return false;}
if(!localStorage["puzzle.game.in.progress"]=="true"){return false;}
boardEdge=parseInt(localStorage["puzzle.boardEdge"]);
blockPixel=parseInt(localStorage["puzzle.blockPixel"]);
imgElement=new Image();
imgElement.src=localStorage["puzzle.image.src"];
gameStatus=new Array(boardEdge);
gameCompStatus=new Array(boardEdge);
for (var i = 0; i < boardEdge; i++) {
    gameStatus[i]=new Array(boardEdge);
    gameCompStatus[i]=new Array(boardEdge);
    for(var j=0;j<boardEdge;j++){
        gameStatus[i][j]=parseInt(localStorage["puzzle.gameStatus."+i+j]);
        var x=(gameStatus[i][j]-1)%boardEdge;
        var y=(gameStatus[i][j]-1-j)/boardEdge;
        drawingContext.drawImage(imgElement,x*blockPixel,y*blockPixel,blockPixel,blockPixel
                                            j*blockPixel,i*blockPixel,blockPixel,blockPixel);
        drawLines();
    }
}
gameStatus[boardEdge-1][boardEdge-1]=0;
gameCompStatus[boardEdge-1][boardEdge-1]=0;

moveCount.textContent=localStorage["puzzle.move.count"];
gameInProgress=(localStorage["puzzle.game.in.progress"] =="true");
emptyBlock=new Cell(parseInt(localStorage["puzzle.empty.block.X"]),parseInt(localStorage["puzzle.empty.block.Y"]));
return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a browser with a good debugger/inspector?  Firefox with Firebug, IE 8 or 9 (which comes with F12 developer tools), and I believe Chrome has it built in too.  Log to the console, step through your code.  Reading the answers below, if any of them are correct it will be immediately apparent with the right JavaScript tools in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="puzzle.js"></script></script>
```

What is this? Is it typo? Or in your real code it is so too? Try to remove them. Javascript should see your functions. Where is declarations for `Init` and `keydown` functions? Does javascript see them?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for any errors? I see one in the loop of `resumeGame`:

```
    drawingContext.drawImage(imgElement,x*blockPixel,y*blockPixel,blockPixel,blockPixel
                                        j*blockPixel,i*blockPixel,blockPixel,blockPixel);
```

should probably be:

```
    drawingContext.drawImage(imgElement,x*blockPixel,y*blockPixel,blockPixel,blockPixel,
        j*blockPixel,i*blockPixel,blockPixel,blockPixel);
```

Comment: That wouldn't cause the function to be undefined.

Comment: Always a good to start checking that your code is valid - a typo in the .js file could very well be the issue here

Answer (score 0):

Your url might be wrong. You are using a relative url instead of an absolute url, consequently the JS file must be in the same folder as the HTML Document.

Try an absolute url (e.g. http://www.servername.com/puzzle/js/puzzle.js") instead and check if that accomplishes anything.